# How to properly store global variables for php server code

Tags: php, mysql, security, global-variables

I am writing php scripts for a server code. These include sign up, log in, and similiar functions. These functions often reference the same database and URLs. I have been reading on stackoverflow and google that the user of a global PHP file and using a simple include is a bad idea. Seen below:

global.php

```
<?php
  $databaseHost = "someurl.com";
  $databaseUser = "adminUser";
  $databasePassword = "adminUsersPassword";
  $databaseName = "dbName";
?>
```

serverFile.php

```
<?php
  include 'global.php';

  //mysql functions that use the variables below

  $databaseHost;
  $databaseUser;
  $databasePassword;
  $databaseName;
?>
```

Can someone explain to me the safest way to do such includes or is it better that I just write all the information directly into every server php file? This seems like it will be hard to keep updated if we change / update our database or change our server host.

If you could also explain why you recommend what you recommend that would be greatly appreciated. I have a very good understanding of other programming languages and hardware (I'm a computer engineer), so in depth explanations are welcome.

Sorry for not having an exact problem, but I am very lost on how to best approach this. Thanks in advance for the stackoverflow knowledge.

Comment: the config-settings-in-a-separate-file is a pretty common approach, and it's fine unless you somehow turn off php processing. all anyone who manages to directly request your config file will see is.. nothing.  you can go further and protect it from direct access with a webserver directive as well if you desire

Comment: I'm going to have to look up some of those terms, but thanks. It sounds secure from what your saying. Now just to learn how to use the config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. The only thing you should do is put the file outside of your web root (`public_html`). That way it can't be accessed directly, but instead can only be accessed from code.

Comment: Thanks. I would l love to see a file example and folder example for setup and reference syntax purposes, but if you don't have an example I am sure I can find one myself.